# Magento Error_log

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log

I'm getting numerous error_log
what could be the reason for this?

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YtuPs87EpiT1Zqa1RMUTJIa28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Instead of attaching the whole file here, extract the key error points and then start some basic debugging first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ini_set() function is disable on your server. Ask your server support to enable the php function ini_set() for your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I've created a ticket in the shortest amount of time the server will look for the help

Comment: this problem could be because of the slowness of our site?   Gtmetrix.com page speed F (12 percent) as it looks  http://2.1m.yt/RA_NgA.png